# why is Windows is truncating the name of a file I create using open() in python 3.6?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, ubuntu

I am attempting to port a python 3.6 program from Ubuntu 18 to Windows 10. In this file I am creating a long string with a date time object in it and using it as a filename. The open() command works fine in ubuntu and creates a long string ending with the ".txt" However Windows 10 does not like this and truncates the filename to 32 bits (I'm not sure if that is on purpose or coincidence.) The code is the same but the operating systems treat if differently.  Here is the code:

```
    # Capture the date time object format to write to log file
    datetime_object = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%I:%M%p on %B %d, %Y")
    print(datetime_object)
    Error_file_name = "ESP32_Company_Error_log_" + datetime_object + ".txt"
    print(Error_file_name)
    Info_file_name = "ESP32_Company_Information_log_" + datetime_object + ".txt"


    #Open the files to write 
    err_fl = open(Error_file_name, "a")
    #print(type(err_fl))
    info_fl = open(Info_file_name, "a")
```

Windows will create a generic file

```
ESP32_Company_Information_log_11
```

Which is not a .txt file and therefor not open it later on. Ubuntu creates 
"ESP32_Company_Information_log_11:15AM on May 14, 2019.txt"

I've tried import os, did not work. I've looked at the type and cannot figure out why a text IO wrapper would have this.

Comment: Windows prohibits ":" in filenames. Althought behaviour of truncation is strange.

Comment: I had to look again. You are correct, The colon " : " is not allowed. Changing this fixed it

Comment: I'm always correct, unless I'm wrong that is. Glad it works. :) I actually realized why filename is truncated as that was main mental excersise here, NTFS allows for alternate data streams which are actually identified by ":" in filename while opening such stream.

Comment: @rAndom69, to clarify, ":" is part of the filepath, not the filename. The complete specification of an NTFS file is "filename:streamname:streamtype". For example, a directory named "dirname" is actually an index stream named "$I30", i.e. "dirname:$I30:$INDEX_ALLOCATION".  (The internal code for the name attribute of a file is 0x30, so the stream name "$I30" indicates it's a filename index. There are other index types that typically aren't seen, such as the "\$Extend\$Reparse:$R:$INDEX_ALLOCATION" index of reparse points.)

Comment: Also, Windows doesn't prohibit ":" in filenames. Microsoft's filesystems prohibit it because it conflicts with [file streams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/FileIO/file-streams) and leads to ambiguities with device names (e.g. "C:" and "NUL:"). Third-party filesystems can allow it. For example, the shared-folder filesystem of VirtualBox allows colon in filenames, as well as pipe and ASCII control characters.

Comment: @eryksun I'm _unsure_ that is entirely correct (nor was my reply but just "lazy"). FAT did not have alternate data streams (FAT32 IIRC yes) so both "calling conventions" "Windows" or "Microsoft" are wrong. Although you're more correct-er than I was :) Unsure why Microsoft prohibited ":" on FAT as part of filepath as drive specification has to be on specific place. You know history of that?

Comment: Nevermind CWD and path issues. Me slow. You actually said it - ambiguities.

Comment: The paths through the I/O manager (e.g. `NtCreateFile`) are the same for all devices, not just those mounted by a filesystem. Devices have a namespace even if it's not a filesystem (e.g. the console's ConDrv supports names such as "CurrentOut"), so enforcing invalid characters in the I/O manager, while possible, just isn't worth it. It's left up to the filesystem. Microsoft does provide a filesystem runtime library that validates legal characters, but these checks are optional. That said, the wildcard characters (`*?"<>`) *should* be reserved, else `FindFirstFile` won't function as documented.

Answer (score 0):

It Appears that the date time format matters rAndom69 you are correct. Changing the format fixed the issue.